# Match a line not ending in digit (with possible trailing white spaces)

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to match a line which doesn't end in a digit (with possibly trailing white spaces. I am using Emacs Regex (and I am open to use other Regex flavors).

1. What are some good regexs to accomplish that?
2. Can we use Possessive Quantifiers. (suppose Possessive Quantifiers work in Emacs Regex)
3. Here are two attempt of mine.

   ```
   [^[:digit:]] *^J
   ```

   where `^J` is the new line character, typed by `C-q C-j`, will match

   ```
   concepts of logic 1
   ```

   But

   ```
   [^[:digit:]] *$
   ```

   doesn't match

   ```
   concepts of logic 1
   ```

   I wonder why there is the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: How about this `.*(?<![\d\s])\s*(?:\r?\n|$)` ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to match either a line that does not end in any char (i.e., is empty) or a line that ends in a character that is not a digit and not a newline char?

Interactively, you would type the regexp to `C-M-s`, this way:

```
\(^$\|[^C-qC-j[:digit:]]\)$
```

Where typing `C-q C-j` inserts a newline char (`C-j`) interactively.  It looks like this in Isearch, where the `^J` is a single (newline) char:

```
\(^$\|[^^J[:digit:]]\)$
```

From Lisp, you would double the backslashes and use `\n` to represent the newline char:

```
\\(^$\\|[^\n[:digit:]]\\)$
```

If you want to allow trailing whitespace, then add `[ \t]*` before the `$`.  For example, interatively:

```
\(^$\|[^C-qC-j[:digit:]]\)[ \t]*$
```